# anchor() function in code igniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to use the anchor function to route a view to a controller, however I wanna pass in some variables such as $groupid,$jurisdictionid and append them to the uri segment argument.

For instance,

$groupid=(input by user)
$jurisdictionid=(input by user)

anchor ('pagetohit/$groupid/$jurisdictionid')

how do I format this correctly since I want those varaibles to take on the values they are assigned before the anchor function takes them and routes the url.

Answer (score 2):

anchor() is internally using site_url(), so you can:

```
anchor(array('pagetohit', $groupid, $jurisdictionid));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use double quotes instead of single quotes.

```
anchor("pagetohit/$groupid/$jurisdictionid")
```

Variables inside double quotes will be replaced with their values automatically. [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple)

Answer (score 1):

We Can Pass More Than One Value Using This. 
For Ex, it will look like this ://...../welcome/deletefiles/3/1

```
<?php echo anchor("welcome/deletefiles/".$row1->FileNo.'/'.$row1->FileID,
                    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="color:red;"></span>',
                    array('onclick' => "return confirm('Do you want delete this record')"))?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**It is for passing a single value**

```
 <?php echo anchor("Home_control/add/{$value->id}",'Add Blog',['class'=>'btn btn-info']); ?>
```

**It is for passing a multiple value**

```
 <?php echo anchor("Home_control/add/{$value->id}/{$value->ids}",'Add Blog',['class'=>'btn btn-info']); ?>
```

**or use this**

```
<?php echo anchor("Home_control/add/$value",'Add Blog',['class'=>'btn btn-info']); ?>
```

1st parameter => Controller name,function name,parameter.

2nd parameter=> Name

3rd parameter=> html attributes

Answer (score 0):

It's simple write double quotes (" ") instead of single quotes ('').

When any variable resides double quote then it takes its value not send direct variable.

Example:

```
anchor("controller/function/$id");
```